# availability.getMode() and availability.isAvailable always returns null and false respectively

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, asmack

I am working on android chat application using `xmpp` protocol , `ejabberd` server and using `asmack` library. I want to display buddies status. But whether the buddy is online or offline it always show offline status, and `availability.getMode()` always returns null and  `availability.isAvailable` always returns false irrespective of buddy is online or offline.

here is my code. thanks in advance...

```
Roster roster = connection.getRoster();



    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
    for (RosterEntry entry : entries) 
    {


    System.out.println("Entry :"+entry);
    Presence availability = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());
    Mode userMode = availability.getMode();
    Log.e("TAG", ""+userMode+" availability :"+availability.isAvailable());

                            retrieveState_mode(availability.getMode(),availability.isAvailable());



                        }


    public static int retrieveState_mode(Mode userMode, boolean isOnline) {
                                    int userState = 0;
                                    *//** 0 for offline, 1 for online, 2 for away,3 for busy*//*
                                    if(userMode == Mode.dnd) {
                                        userState = 3;
                                    } else if (userMode == Mode.away || userMode == Mode.xa) {   
                                        userState = 2;
                                    } else if (isOnline) {
                                        userState = 1;
                                    }
                                    return userState;
                            }
```

Comment: are you able to get entries ? I am trying to get users list but roster.getEntries() method always returns null to me, do we have to do any settings on ejabberd panel/server ?

Answer (score 0):

In your code instead of using availability.getMode() use availabilty.getType() and check whether it is Presence.Type.available.